# create instance of android.accounts.Account in qt c++ code

Tags: android, c++, qt, java-native-interface, qandroidjniobject

I am trying to use the android AccountManager from qt c++ code. To add a account, I want to create an instance of `android.accounts.Account`, I am trying to do this with this code:

```
jstring jUsername = QAndroidJniObject::fromString(username).object<jstring>();
jstring jPassword = QAndroidJniObject::fromString(password).object<jstring>();
jstring jType = QAndroidJniObject::fromString(type).object<jstring>();
qDebug()<<"Creating";
QAndroidJniObject accountObject("android.accounts.Account","(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V",jUsername,jType);
qDebug()<<"Inserting";
```

The code segfaults at the line, where the `accountObject` is created ("Creating" is printed, "Inserting" not):

```
JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed deleted global reference 0x100e46
JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed deleted global reference 0xe46
```

I read this occurs, if I call a method with a wrong signature, but the signature is right (see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/Account.html#Account%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it, the way you're creating your strings are causing your problem.

```
jstring jUsername = QAndroidJniObject::fromString(username).object<jstring>();
```

What this does is create an anonymous temporary `QAndroidJniObject` (returned by `fromString`), which you then extract the wrapped `jobject` from (and cast it to a `jstring`). By the time execution of that statement finishes the lifetime of that `QAndroidJniObject` is over, and the reference it held to the wrapped `jobject` will be released.

You could change your code to somethine like this:

```
auto qjUsername = QAndroidJniObject::fromString(username);
auto jUsername = qjUsername.object<jstring>();
```

Or to:

```
jstring jUsername = env->NewLocalRef(QAndroidJniObject::fromString(username).object<jstring>());
```

Assuming that you have a way of getting the `JNIEnv*`.
If you create a new reference you should probably also delete it with `DeleteLocalRef` when you don't need it anymore.